# Powering ESP32 with Raspberry Pi 4 USB Port

Tags: pi-4

I have a RPi 4. I want to read the serial output of ESP32 over USB, so I connected my ESP32 development board to the USB port of my RPi 4 directly. I’m really concerned whether I’ve damaged the USB port in doing so. Can the RPi deliver enough power to a ESP32 board with no external components attached without any over current issues? Have I damaged my board? Is my board safe?

PS: ESP32 draws around 160 mA over USB from RPi 4.

Comment: Please check the Raspberry Pi's logs for any messages related to overcurrent protection triggering.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#maximum-power-output) you can draw up to 1.2A across all the 4 USB ports combined, so 160mA should be fine assuming your power supply to the PI 4 can handle it.